# $100 + [110/(1+r)] = [1/ (1+r)] + [(232 /(1+r)^2 ]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Need to learn how to solve this: $100 + \frac{110}{1 + r} = \frac{1}{1 + r} + \frac{232}{(1 + r)^{2}}$. Checked [this](http://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html) site  got to the 3rd line and am completely lost. Can someone help me solve for r line by line please?

Comment: It's a little hard to read without the formatting, but what I would do, if I understand correctly, is multiply everything by $(1+r)^2$, and then try to solve it like a quadratic.

Comment: (to get the math formatting, enclose everything in money signs, and for fractions put "\frac{}{}" and then in the first set of braces, the numerator, and the second set of braces, the denominator. Exponents are done with the ^ symbol like you've got.)

Comment: @AlfredYerger 's suggestion is clearly the easiest and most immediate way to remove fractions from the equation. However, one must also add the condition that $r\neq -1$ when doing this, just in case you get that as a solution when solving the resulting quadratic. This is necessary because otherwise the first step would not be valid (you would be multiplying both sides by zero in that case, which typically alters the solution set of the equation).

Comment: Another way to avoid @MPW's $r \ne -1$ condition is to solve the equation as a quadratic of $\frac{1}{1+r}$ rather than $(1+r)$.

Comment: @lastresort: True, but at the cost of having to solve an additional pair of equations for $r$ after solving the quadratic. And, the same condition will apply to them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

$$100+\frac{110}{1+r}=\frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{232}{(1+r)^2}$$

$$100(1+r)^2+110(1+r)-(1+r)-232=0$$

$$100+200r+100r^2+110+110r-1-r-232=0$$

$$100r^2+309r-23=0$$

Can you proceed using quadratic formula?

Comment: What is the formula you use to go from line 2 to line 3? mainly expanding 100(1+r)^2?

Comment: $100(1+r)^2=100(r^2+2r+1)=100r^2+200r+100$

Comment: Thank you soo much!! I have been working on this for over an hour and could not for the life of me remember this stuff.

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a scientific/ financial calculator?

Comment: Find the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the problem, let $A = 1 + r.$ The equation becomes
$$100 + 110A^{-1} = A^{-1} + 232A^{-2}.$$

Multiply both sides by $A^{2}$ to get
$$100A^{2} + 110A = A + 232$$
$$100A^{2} + 109A - 232 = 0.$$

I leave you to solve the quadratic for $A$ and find the corresponding solutions for $r.$